# How to print the element text in Playwright Python?

Tags: python, automation, automated-tests, playwright

How to print the element text in playwright python?

```py
self.error_alert_text = page.locator("#alert .modal > p")
```

I have tried with

```
print(self.error_alert_text.get_by_text()))
```

But nothing has been printed. How I can print the element value?

Also how can I concatenate the string with printing the object? i.e:

```py
print("test print" + self.error_alert_text.get_by_text()))
```

Answer (score 1):

`get_by_text()` method doesn't gets text, it gets `ElementHandle` that has text that defined in method argument.

To get alert text you should use `text_content()` or `inner_text()` on `ElementHandle` instead.

```py
page.locator('#alert .modal > p').wait_for(state='visible')
print(f"Alert text: {page.locator('#alert .modal > p').text_content()}")
```

or

```
page.locator('#alert .modal > p').wait_for(state='visible')
print(f"Alert text: {page.locator('#alert .modal > p').inner_text()}")
```

[text_content reference](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-elementhandle#element-handle-text-content)

[inner_text reference](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-elementhandle#element-handle-text-content)

Comment: Good answer, but is `page.locator('#alert .modal > p').wait_for(state='visible')` actually necessary? I thought locators already awaited for the element to be visible, so this line seems superfluous.

Comment: @ggorlen interesting point. From their documentation I see that Playwright for text_content and inner_text waits for element to be attached and doesn't wait for visibility. https://playwright.dev/docs/actionability . Do you have some insights that it actually waits for this state? In my project I use it to avoid flakiness. If it not necessary, I'll remove this line, just need some clarity. :)

Comment: I think you're right, good call!